# How to deeply customize an element-plus component?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, themes, customization, element-plus

I am trying to **build my own components** with the library **element-plus** as a base.

I have great **success** so far when it comes to easy stuff like **colors**, which can be overridden easily [forwarding the default theme](https://element-plus.org/en-US/guide/theming.html)

However, when it comes to things **built-in** a component, I find myself stuck.

For example, the [Alert component](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/alert.html#with-icon-and-description) is fairly customizable by default.

I was able with css to modify both color and shape, as well as using built-in API to custom the closing icon for example.

[Image of Alert Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWSMG.png)

However, I **failed** so far to change the success / info etc icons element-plus provides, since they are added programmatically **inside the component code**. Furthermore, the color of this icon is inherited from the background and I failed to change it alone.

[My Alert Component Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySs37.png)

The source of the Alert component can be found [here](https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus/blob/dev/packages/components/alert/src/alert.vue#L30)

And it **seems** the element plus components are **not customizable further** from what they explicitly let you modify.

Am I missing something ? Can this be achieved by extending the components ? Or by heavy css ?

Thanks a lot,